# C# MVC swap position of keys and values in dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, listbox, swap

I made a dictionary as follows:

> ```
> new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();
> ```

Now I set the Keys and the Values into two different listboxes. When I click on the first listbox with the keys inside, it will shows the associated values in the second listbox e.g.

> Key:
>   Integration
>
> > Values:
> >     Identify the safety hazards
> >     Locate and describe the safety devices

The Listboxes looks like this:

[image]

I wanna now swap the values "Identify the safety hazards" and "Locate and describe the safety devices" like the following picture shows:
[image]

It works with the javascript visually, but the dictionary is still the same. I have to swap it in the dictionary.

Can somebody help me? It's really important.

Thank you!

Comment: so the tasks you are trying to swap are within the IList<string> correct?

Comment: yes that's correct.

Comment: what I see is not swapping keys and values but just simple list position swap if I understand correctly

Comment: But only for the values.

Comment: your key is name of lesson, and the ILists contains all the tasks for that lesson correct? so if you wish to swap the order of the tasks all you have to do is swap the List index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your key is name of lesson, and the `ILists` contains all the tasks for that lesson

In order to swap the position of the tasks you don't need to swap key and values but the order of them inside the list

something like

```
void Swap(IList<string> list, int a, int b)
{
    string temp = list[a];
    list[a] = list[b]
    list[b] = temp;
}
```